# Saving output loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a vectored equation via solving the equation element by element through a loop among the vector elements. I am currently using vpasolve to find the solution but I am struggling with saving the output for each row as I loop through the vector. How do I save the output of the last loop into a vector 100x1? Thank you for your help! I am new to matlab.

```
output = [1:100]'
govt = ones(100,1)*.3
labor=zeros(100,1)
consumption=zeros(100,1)
gamma=.6
eta=.7
beta=.96
delta=.5


for k=1:length(output)
    if mod(output(k),2)==0
        output(k)=.8
    else output(k)=1.2
    end
end

%%%%%%my problem is down here%%%%%%%%

save=zeros(100,1)
for k=1:length(output)
vpasolve(((x^eta)*(1+delta)+(x^(eta+1))*delta)/(((output(k)*x-govt(k))^(-gamma))*(1+delta)+((output(k)*x-govt(k))^(-gamma+1))*delta)==output(k), x)
save(k)=int64(x)
end
```

Comment: Where is `x` getting set? Also, I'm guessing you need to take assign an output from `vpasolve`.

Comment: hey! well x is the variable I am solving for. that's what I am trying to save/assign into a vector.